# clang-ctags error: ImportError: No module named clang.cindex

Tags: clang

clang-ctags is producing the following error

```
$ clang-ctags trace make
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/clang-ctags", line 9, in <module>
    import clang.cindex
ImportError: No module named clang.cindex
```

Or

```
$ clang-ctags
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/clang-ctags", line 9, in <module>
    import clang.cindex
ImportError: No module named clang.cindex
```

I cannot find anything on the internet and I don't know python either. Can anyone solve this please?

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Ubuntu you can install the Python bindings to Clang with the package 
`python-clang-3.4` or `python-clang-3.5`

To install it just run:

`sudo apt-get install python-clang-3.4`

Comment: Thanks - not using ubuntu - and I don't trust/understand any software that I cannot build myself :-) - not a package fan

Comment: CUrrent version is python-clang-3.9